# Selector Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery, I made a complex selector but it's not working. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$("#gig:nth-child('3'):contains(:not('a'))")
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's rather impossible to tell without knowing what the HTML is and which ones you want targeted.

Comment: Why isn't it working? What is it supposed to do? Did you forget some spaces?

Comment: No selector should need to be this complex. Have you considered another solution such as using a class or id to simplify your selector?

Comment: I wonder what the jQuery query plan is for this selector

Comment: Please pick an answer and mark it as accepted with the checkmark so the community can know which one solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to select an element whose text doesn't contain the letter a, you'll want to switch the positions of `:contains()` and `:not()` as `:contains()` isn't supposed to contain another selector. Try this:

```
$("#gig:nth-child(3):not(:contains('a'))")
```

If you meant an `a` element rather than the letter a, use `:has()`:

```
$("#gig:nth-child(3):not(:has(a))")
```

Answer (score 1):

`:contains('a')` matches elements containing the letter `a` in its text. If you're looking for elements without a child `<a>` link

```
$("#gig:nth-child(3):not(:has(a))")
```

Answer (score 1):

nth-child accepts an integer not a string.

`$("#gig:nth-child(3)")`

Comment: @Esailijia: It's useful in case the element with the ID is surrounded by siblings that might change in number or position.